# no default constructor exists

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm having some trouble with a class that was working fine and now doesn't seem to want to work at all.

The error is `"No appropriate default constructor available"`

I am using the class in two places I'm making a list of them and initializing then adding them to the list.

**Vertice3f.h**

```
#pragma once 
#include "Vector3f.h"

// Vertice3f hold 3 floats for an xyz position and 3 Vector3f's 
//  (which each contain 3 floats) for uv, normal and color

class Vertice3f{
private:
    float x,y,z;
    Vector3f uv, normal, color;

public:
    // If you don't want to use a UV, Normal or Color 
    //  just pass in a Verctor3f with 0,0,0 values
    Vertice3f(float _x, float _y, float _z, Vector3f _uv, 
              Vector3f _normal, Vector3f _color);
    ~Vertice3f();
};
```

**Vertice3f.cpp**

```
#include "Vertice3f.h"

Vertice3f::Vertice3f(float _x, float _y, float _z, 
                     Vector3f _uv, Vector3f _normal, Vector3f _color){
    x = _x;
    y = _y;
    z = _z;
    uv = _uv;
    normal = _normal;
    color = _color;
}
```

It is being using in my OBJModelLoader class as follows:

```
list<Vertice3f> vert3fList;

Vertice3f tvert = Vertice3f(
            x = (float)atof(
            vertList[i].substr(
                vertList[i].find("v") + 1,
                vertList[i].find(" ", vertList[i].find("v") + 2, 10)
                ).c_str()
            ),
            y = (float)atof(
                vertList[i].substr(
                    vertList[i].find(" ", vertList[i].find("v") + 4, 10) + 1,
                    vertList[i].find(" ", vertList[i].find("v") + 13, 10)
                ).c_str()
            ),
            z = (float)atof(
                vertList[i].substr(
                vertList[i].find(" ", vertList[i].find("v") + 13, 10) + 1,
                vertList[i].find(" ", vertList[i].find("v") + 23, 10)
                ).c_str()
            ),
            ::Vector3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f),::Vector3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f),::Vector3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f)
        );

        vert3fList.push_back(
            tvert
        );
```

I have tried defining a default constructor myself so in the .h I put

```
Vertice3f();
```

and in the cpp

```
Vertice3f::Vertice3f(){
x = 0.0f;
y = 0.0f;
z = 0.0f;
uv = Vector3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
normal = Vector3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
color = Vector3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
}
```

So, I'm not sure why it can't find a default constructor or how to appease the compiler. I'm sure it's user error because the compiler probably knows what it's doing.
Any help is greatly appreciated, I will answer any other questions you have, just ask.

Comment: `Vertice3f();` is declared public?

Comment: Please amend your solution directly into the code so we can see a complete version of what is supposed to work.

Comment: Yes. it is declared as public.

Also I'm not sure what you mean by "amend your solution directly into the code"? Do you mean you want the whole files or the sln file?

Comment: Does `Vector3f` have a default constructor?  If not, you'll need to initialise `uv`, `normal`, and `color` in `Vertice3f`'s initialisation lists.  (You should do that anyway - it's more efficient)

Comment: "No appropriate default constructor" for **what class**??? From your code it looks quite possible that the problem is `Vector3f` class, not `Vertice3f` class. Your constructor attempts to default-construct `Vector3f` members. If that's the problem, then adding default constructor to `Vertice3f` won't change anything.

Comment: @user962179 You posted code with an obvious problem, there is no default constructor. Then you posted a default constructor and said "it still doesn't work when I add this." Show us how you added it. See http://sscce.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess that the missing default constructor is the default constructor of `Vector3f` class, not of `Vertice3f` class. Your constructor of `Vertice3f` attempts to default-construct its `Vector3f` members, which leads to the error.

This is why your attempts to provide default constructor for `Vertice3f` don't change anything. The problem lies, again, with `Vector3f`.

To fix it either provide all necessary default constructors (assuming it agrees with your design), or rewrite the constructor of `Vertice3f` by using initializer list instead of in-body assignment

```
Vertice3f::Vertice3f(float _x, float _y, float _z, 
                     Vector3f _uv, Vector3f _normal, Vector3f _color) :
    x(_x), y(_y), z(_z), uv(_uv), normal(_normal), color(_color)
  {}
```

This version no longer attempts to default-construct anything. And using initializer list instead of in-body assignment is a good idea in any case.

Comment: This is what the problem was, I was just reading the error too quickly and read Vector3f as Vertice3f. Thanks for the help.